# Itô-Tanaka formula for a cadlag semimartingale (with a jump process)

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, poisson-process

Let $T<\infty$ and $Y$ be some cadlag semimartingale such that : 
$$
dY_t = r_tdt + \sigma_t dW_t + \beta_tdN_t,\ t\in [0,T]
$$

Where $W$ is a $1$-dimensional Brownian Motion, $N$ be a jump process and $r,\sigma,\beta$ are assumed to be bounded.

My questions are:

- How to develop $((Y_t)^+)_{t\in[0,T]}$? Do the processes $r,\sigma,\beta$ bounded is enough ?
- Does the Itô-Tanaka's formula works, since we have a jump process ?
- How could we express the Local time term in this case ?
- Is there a reference for this specific problem (article, book ...) ? it could be enough for me.

---

My idea is maybe to develop Itô-Tanaka formula on every $[\tau_k,\tau_{k+1}[$.

I think we can write $Y$ such that
$$
(Y_t)^+=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}1_{\tau_{k}\leq t<\tau_{k+1}}(X_t+C_t)^+
$$
where $X=A+M$ with $A$ is a finite variation term (i.e. $dt$), $M$ be the continuous (Brownian) martingale part, $C$ be the cadlag part.

For a reference there is Chapter IV, Section 7 in *Ph. Protter. Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations. Springer, Berlin, Second edition, 2005.*

If someone can give me more ideas thank you.